# Breeze server side entity creation

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I need to create entities on the server when a client sends updates to the server (these entries created on the server are mainly for audit reports)
As per the [breeze documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/contextprovider) I should do the following on the server:

```
protected override Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> BeforeSaveEntities(
            Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap)
{
     ...
     var auditInput= new AuditItem();
     auditInput.CreationTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
     var newEntity = _breezeContext.CreateEntityInfo(auditInput);
     if (!saveMap.ContainsKey(typeof (auditInput)))
          saveMap[typeof (auditInput)] = new List<EntityInfo>();
     ...
}

public class AuditItem
{
    public int AuditItemId      { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime    { get; set; }
}
```

This works very well when only one `AuditItem` is created per save. However, when multiple of these entities are created on the server on the same save operation, EF screams out with the following error message:

> AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict
>   with another object in the ObjectStateManager

Debugging this shows that the `ObjectStateManager` is holding multiple instances of the `AuditInput` with a key of `0` which makes the state manager think all of these are the same entities.

**QUESTION**
How can I help breeze generate different entities when creating them in the server? Is there a way to force it to generate new keys for created entities?

Comment: Why can't you give them new ids directly within this method?

Comment: Well, I thought Breeze would take care of that as I am adding those entities into the `saveMap`. I thought about this but I wanted to make sure this can't be done with Breeze first. Furthermore, I don't know how to give them IDs that are not already in use. Any idea?

Comment: if the purpose is creating new entities of Audit data, why not use another `dbContext` and implement the insert/update operation inside `AfterSaveEntities` ?